# Who did AWB steal their time machine from?

Tags: harry-turtledove

In *The Guns of the South*, South Africans in the AWB from 2014 use a stolen time machine capable of traveling exactly 150 years into the past to give AK-47s to the Confederate States of America, changing the outcome of the Civil War.

The book was written more than 20 years ago, and the AWBers were from THE DISTANT FUTURE of 2014.

In dialog, one of the AWBers mentions that they stole their time machine.  I haven't read the book in a while and no longer have a copy, but I thought that it was never made explicit who they stole it from.  I always assumed either a government or a university history department or something like that.  However, lately, in a couple of different places, I've seen it mentioned that they stole it from somebody else from even further in the future.

Is there anything in the book supporting this, or is it a fan retcon due to the fact that time machines are not in common use in 2014?

Comment: We have three and a half months to find out!

Comment: I've just skimmed the book, and I can't find any mention of where the time machine came from other than, as you say, Rhoodie claiming: *We did not manage to obtain even the small one we have-steal it, not to mince words-until just a few months ago-just a few months ago up in 2013, that is.*